# Power Shell Stop-Process throwa error that the process does not exist

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to execute the following script

```
$WonderwareProcess = Get-Process -Name "Studio Manager"
Write-Output $WonderwareProcess
Stop-Process -Name $WonderwareProcess -Force
$Result = Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.HasExited}
Write-Output $Result
Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

It outputs the following

```
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName                                                                                                                                                                                              
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------                                                                                                                                                                                              
    448      83    25776      58408   332     5.68   3264 Studio Manager                                                                                                                                                                                           
Stop-Process : Cannot find a process with the name "System.Diagnostics.Process (Studio Manager)". Verify the process name and call the cmdlet again.
At C:\Users\Winuser\Desktop\Kill Wonderware.ps1:3 char:13
+ Stop-Process <<<<  -Name $WonderwareProcess -Force
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (System.Diagnost...Studio Manager):String) [Stop-Process], ProcessCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoProcessFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StopProcessCommand
```

How can Get-Process find the process but Stop-Process can't

This is Windows 7 SP1, with Power Shell 2

Comment: `Stop-Process -Name $WonderwareProcess.Name -Force` or `$WonderwareProcess|Stop-Process -Force` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass a value of type `string[]` as `-NAME` parameter of the `Stop-Process` cmdlet:

```
(Get-Command Stop-Process).Definition
```

> ```
> Stop-Process [-Id] <int[]> [-PassThru] [-Force] [-WhatIf] [-Confirm] [<CommonParameters>]
>
> Stop-Process -Name <string[]> [-PassThru] [-Force] [-WhatIf] [-Confirm] [<CommonParameters>]
>
> Stop-Process [-InputObject] <Process[]> [-PassThru] [-Force] [-WhatIf] [-Confirm] [<CommonParameters>]
> ```

Otherwise, PowerShell does an attempt of *implicit type conversion*, e.g. something like

- `"$WonderwareProcess"` or
- `[string]$WonderwareProcess` or
- `$WonderwareProcess.ToString()`.

Any of those type conversions returns `System.Diagnostics.Process (Studio Manager)`, in your case.

Use either

- `Stop-Process -Id $WonderwareProcess.Id -Force` or
- `Stop-Process -Name $WonderwareProcess.Name -Force` or
- `Stop-Process -InputObject $WonderwareProcess -Force` or even
- `$WonderwareProcess | Stop-Process -Force`